# Indesign Server sampleclient java (SDK) not working

Tags: java, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I'm trying to test run the sample client for Java provided in the InDesign Server SDK.

When I try to create and build the project in IntelliJ or eclipse, I'm getting unresolved symbols for the following classes from the SampleClient.java file.

```
import localhost.Service_wsdl.Service;
import localhost.Service_wsdl.ServiceLocator;
import localhost.Service_wsdl.ServiceStub;

import com.adobe.ns.InDesign.soap.IDSPScriptArg;
import com.adobe.ns.InDesign.soap.RunScriptParameters;
import com.adobe.ns.InDesign.soap.holders.DataHolder;
```

I also tried to convert the IDSP.wsdl file into java code using "wsimport -keep" command but still  did not get all the java files.

Please let me know in case I'm missing some steps. I have found similar issues mentioned in the  Adobe Community portal also but did not get the solution.

I'm able to test run the sampleclient.exe made in C++ language successfully.